# How to emulate IE8 environment?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, emulation

I'm developing asp.net website on IE10/Windows 8 + VS2012

Users noticed some artifacts and they use IE8. If I use F12 tools and set site to IE8 I don't see it. I need real IE8 for dev/test/

How do I emulate it properly?

Comment: Did you test it on another machine where installation of IE 8 is possible? Never believe users! :)

Comment: Yes, I remote desktop to one machine with IE8. But I want to know how to duplicate it on my machine so I can effectively fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may install VirtualPC images with different IE versions for free from
[this Microsoft provided page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575)

Comment: I can do that, but where do I get images with different versions?

Comment: Just click on download button - it shows list of files to choose from.

Answer (score 6):

Tip for who is using WIndows 10: By default you get MS Edge on your taskbar, and not IE. Just open a website on Edge, go to settings in the right top, and choose "Open with Internet Explorer" You can then pin the new IE window to open it straight next time. Only on this IE window you can choose to emulate other IE versions.

Answer (score 2):

click F12 on Internet explorer to activate the debuger
find the emulator mode and choose your version

Comment: the question is how to emulate IE8

Comment: emulate: match or surpass (a person or achievement), typically by imitation.   Emulation mode is not properly named as it does not match or surpass native functionality it therefor does not emulate.

Comment: Furthermore if you read the question again.  The OP said I can not see what they are seeing if I use F12 what can I do different.  And you said use F12...

Comment: ok i must agree with u but i found it personnaly to reproduce quite closely my  page display of native IE8

Comment: Mostly I see errors in javascrip and with some html tags.  When I test in IE compatibility mode it always misses the gotyas and then the client comes back and said things such as xyz does not work.  I now just ignore the compatibility mode all together

Answer (score 0):

what i do to emulate a specific ie version is to use the 'x-ua-compatible' meta tag. and e.g. to emulate ie8, we use the following line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

if you want to delve into the mysteries of x-ua-compatible tag, you should try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do) link.